# Scala Class Methods

Tags: scala, class, methods

I'm new to programming and Scala. I don't understand what's going on on second line of this code. All I can understand is A method(add) is being created with Class(Number) being the Argument. After that I draw blank. I would really appreciate if someone could interpret this code. Thanks

```
scala> class Number(val i:Int){
    def add(num: Number) = new Number(i + num.i)
}
scala> (new Number(23)).add(new Number(-1)).i
res18: Int = 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand few things here

1) `add` is the method of the class `Number`. So, add method can be invoked on the instance (object) of the `Number` class.

Thats what is happening here

`(new Number(23)).add(new Number(-1)).i`

```
              ^
```

2) `add` method takes `Number` object as the input parameter. So, you can add `Number` instance to `add` method

`(new Number(23)).add(new Number(-1)).i`

```
                  ^
```

3) `add` method method returns `Number` type and Number class contains `i` as the public val (variable). So, you can do `numberInstance.i` to get the value of the Integer in the Number class

thats what is happening here

`(new Number(23)).add(new Number(-1)).i`

```
                                  ^
```

So, finally

`23 - 1` is the result.

> add method takes `i` value of the instance on which it is invoked and adds it to the `i` value of instance which is given as input parameter to it and creates a Number instance from the result (wraps the number with Number class). That is what is happening.

Comment: what is this part doing?      = new Number(i + num.i)

Comment: @GauravSharma that do you mean by `this` part ?

Comment: = new Number(i + num.i)

Comment: @GauravSharma It is creating a `Number` instance with sum of `i`s. Look at the last statement in my answer

Comment: Now I get It! Thank you so much!!1

Answer (score 0):

An instance of `Number` is created (`(new Number(23))`). It can be used right away, so the next thing is to call the `add()` method on it, which returns a `Number`.
Then we get the member variable `i` from the `Number` instance

Answer (score 0):

After the `=` is the body of the method.  For methods that are only a single statement, curly braces are not needed.  Return type can also be omitted because the compiler can figure out what the return type should be (`Number` in this case).